# how do you decorate a visited link?

Tags: html, css, localhost

Why isn't  `text-decoration: line-through;` working on a visited link? When I click the link it only seems to change the color of the text but ignores text-decoration..

code:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com">youtube</a> 


<style>
a:link {
    color:#666;
        text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #F00;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

</style>
```

I want to be able to do this with my links [example](http://watchseries.lt/episode/keeping_up_with_the_kardashians_s6_e7.html). Right when you click 'watch this link' it changes and puts a red line through.

Comment: Good question. text-decoration didn't work correct in :visited state.

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to style visited links in this way by design.

[See this post](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645786)

The site you have referenced has used javascript and jquery (not very well) to add the styling:

```
onclick="$(this).css('color','#AE3939'); $(this).css('text-decoration','line-through');"
```

You will see if you refresh the page after clicking the link it won't keep the styling so therefore isn't styling `:visited` as you are describing

Answer (score 0):

I visited the link you posted. It works perfectly for me. Using Google Chrome.